# what does a web framework take care of for the programmer?

Tags: javascript, django, html

If the framework manages the HTML/ CSS/ javascript, does a programmer still need to know the javascript language? Or is that taken care of in the abstraction of the framework?

I wanted to make a graphical game/ application using the html5 canvas/ webgl/ whatever other libraries are available to do so. Would it be more effective for me to go through a web framework such as django? I'm not really sure what advantages it offers. I think that if I wanted to create a well designed dynamic site in an effective way, I would use a framework. But if I didn't care about appearance, or if I'm just learning, then am I better off just playing with javascript and html5 first?

Comment: Whenever acquainting myself with a new language, I take some time and learn top level concepts: Objects, Strings (especially string manipulation functions), Data Types (if its a hard typed language), Math, Loop and conditional constructs. Once you know that you can focus on the framework but know enough to get yourself out of trouble.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, you could easily use a framework to simplify your development but remember this:  With every framework or tool that simplifies development, you lose a bit of control.

Eventually, you will come to the point where you need to understand css/JavaScript, or whatever the underlying technology is, in order to accomplish some task.  In that situation you'll be at a point where you need to learn the "hard" stuff.

Even before you get to that point, however, I'd strongly recommend learning the basics of the underlying technology so that you can see what the tools do.  There are many reasons for this, but the most important ones are:

1. As mentioned previously, sooner or later you'll need to anyway.
2. If you don't know the underlying technology, you'll struggle and waste a lot of time trying to understand why the pages/apps generated by the framework don't behave the way you want them to.
3. Troubleshooting is harder
4. It's ***really*** easy for a novice developer to pick up a framework and start doing ***really*** stupid things with it.  Things that can lead to security holes, leaking sensitive data, exposing yourself and customers to risk.

   - Some frameworks, of course, protect novice developers from things like SQL Injection, etc, but not all.  It takes someone who understands what the tools are doing "under the hood" to tell the difference.

Of course, there is a limit to how much you need to know.

As an analogy, it would be foolish to drive a car without taking the time to learn the basics of how it operates, and how to be safe with it.  But to drive a car, you don't need to know how to take apart the engine.  If you're one of the guys who wants to be able to take apart the engine (and put it back together), great!  You'll be one of the experts in at least one area of the automotive field.

The same goes with development.  Different people need/want different depths of knowledge...

But for the web, at least knowing the basics of HTML, css, and JavaScript is a must.  It's like learning the difference between Diesel and Gasoline before filling up your tank.  It's basic knowledge every web developer needs.

Comment: This is not a subjective question. It is a general question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13693/discussion-between-david-stratton-and-marcin)

Answer (score 2):

A framework is often developed for the purpose of making larger tasks easier by taking several steps and making them user-friendly. In addition to this, you'll often find that they include configuration files and auto-installers to ease the setup of server components (databases, for instance) so that non-technical users have an ease of use.

The largest issue with this, however, is when users run into errors or warnings that they are unable to debug because the basis for the problem can only be acknowledged with (often) small amounts of expertise in the core languages that the framework was based on.

Quite simply put, you may not need to learn Javascript to use your said library, but it is highly suggested that you understand the inner workings so that you may easily debug and solve problems you have in the near future.

Enjoy and good luck!